# Why does my code keep skipping my else statement for c++?

Tags: c++

I'm doing some programming exercises in a book for school and the exercise is about determining if the sides that are entered by the user indicate if it is a right-angle triangle.

To figure that out you have to do the Pythagorean theorem which is a^2 + b^2 = c^2. I wrote an `if` statement that asks if (side1 * side1) + (side2 * side2) = (side3 * side3) then it's a right triangle and if it's not I wrote an `else` statement to print that it's not a right triangle. Below is the code that I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int side1=0, side2=0, side3=0;

    cout << "Enter the first side of the triangle: " << endl;
    cin >> side1;

    cout << "Enter the second side of the triangle: " << endl;
    cin >> side2;

    cout << "Enter the third side of the triangle: " << endl;
    cin >> side3;

    if ((side1 * side1) + (side2 * side2) == side3 * side3)
    {
      cout << "It is a right angled triangle" << endl;
      exit(1);
    }

    else
    {
      cout << "It is not a right angled triangle" << endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The response that I keep getting from my code is that everything is a right triangle which is what I don't want.

Comment: What if `side1 == 5, side2 == 4, side3 == 3`, that's still sides of right triangle. You may need to sort sides before check.

Comment: Running your code, If you enter 3, 4, 5 is says 'It is a right angled triangle' and if I enter 1, 2, 3 it says 'It is not a right angled triangle'. Your code isn't 100% right as per the above comment but it is 'working'

Comment: What exactly is your question? You mention your `else` doesn't work, but what inputs are you using? Rather than having `cin`, which can't be reproduced easily, you should instead hardcode some input temporarily while you fix your issue, or at least [edit] your question to mention what input your using.

Comment: @3Dave * has higher precedence than ==, paren would be nice but not needed.

Comment: Although it's working fine. You should use an array. Sort the array to find largest value and compare it with other two sides.

Comment: @SatnamSingh why arrays? It doesn't makes sense to use an array and sort them to find *largest value*. What do you want?

Comment: So that it gives you right output no matter in what order the inputs are. Now he is considering 3rd input as the highest value.

Comment: this is a nice lesson ; the program is correct; the problem is elsewhere - as I looked up Mr Pythagoras has stated that for all right-angled triangles -the square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares on the other two sides. So you need to find the hypotenuse and put it to the right of the equation or ask user to enter it :)

Comment: Your program is correct as far as it goes. If I enter sides `3`, `4`, and `5`, it reports that it's a right triangle. If I enter `3`, `4`, and `4`, it reports that it isn't. As others have mentioned it detects a right triangle only if you enter the length of the hypotenuse last, but that doesn't explain your description that "everything is a right triangle". Your question needs to include sample input and output (unless you hardwire some fixed input into the program).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `if ((side1 * side1) + (side2 * side2) == side3 * side3)` doesn't need all those parentheses. `if (side1 * side1 + side2 * side2 == side3 * side3)` does exactly the same thing, and is easier to read once you get used to reading code.

Answer (score 2):

You should sort the lengths into order as C must be the hypotenuse (the longest side) for Pythagoras' theorem to work. Collect your ints in a std::array and use std::sort, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   array<int,3> side;

   cout << "Enter the first side of the triangle: " << endl;
   cin >> side[0];

   cout << "Enter the second side of the triangle: " << endl;
   cin >> side[1];

   cout << "Enter the third side of the triangle: " << endl;
   cin >> side[2];

   std::sort( begin(side), end(side) );

   if ((side[0] * side[0]) + (side[1] * side[1]) == side[2] * side[2])
   {
      cout << "It is a right angled triangle" << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "It is not a right angled triangle" << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Just checking that side[2] is the longest isn't sufficicent to determine whether the triangle is right-angle or not. You need to put the longest side in the equation in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I managed to get my code to work, I talked with my instructor this morning and she said that I was supposed to calculate for the other sides for my code to work. The code below is my fixed code that works.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int side1 = 0, side2 = 0, side3 = 0, side = 0, sidehyp = 0;

cout << "Enter the first side of the triangle: " << endl;
cin >> side1;

cout << "Enter the second side of the triangle: " << endl;
cin >> side2;

cout << "Enter the third side of the triangle: " << endl;
cin >> side3;

side = (side1*side1) + (side2*side2);
    sidehyp = (side3*side3);


    if (side1 * side1 + side2 * side2 == side3 * side3)
    {
    cout << "It is a right angled triangle" << endl;
    }

    else if (side2 * side2 + side3 * side3 == side1 * side1)
    {
        cout << "It is a right angled triangle" << endl;
    }

    else if (side3 * side3 + side1 * side1 == side2 * side2)
    {
        cout << "It is a right angled triangle" << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "It is not a right angled triangle" << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to get rid of side and sidehyp, they are not needed.